# grep string with quotes from file not working

Tags: bash, sed, grep, escaping

I have a file which contains:

```
2016-08-15 21:02:59,007: 233-670-rundeck-dispatch-script.tmp.sh: Info: Arg: -H server -S SrvCtrl,SNMP -A \"restart\" -CS \"Undefined\" -RS \"Undefined\" -CT \"Undefined\" -RT \"Undefined\" --LogServer logserver:5610
```

As I'm trying to tail an executing log, I'm checking if the logfile contains the most current log. and see if this string exists. I tried with grep -F, grep -E, grep -FFxq
So in short it comes down to this:

```
CurrentLog="2016-08-15 21:02:59,007: 233-670-rundeck-dispatch-script.tmp.sh: Info: Arg: -H server -S SrvCtrl,SNMP -A \"restart\" -CS \"Undefined\" -RS \"Undefined\" -CT \"Undefined\" -RT \"Undefined\" --LogServer logserver:5610"
```

Please note that CurrentLog is filled like this:

```
CurrentLog=$(echo "$OutputTail" | jq ".entries[$EntryCoun‌​t].log" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' )
```

Meaning I can't just single quote.

```
grep -Fxq "$CurrentLog" "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/DAF-988e7506-36c3-47e3-8ef2-428309e2c7f7-670.log"
```

It seems like I need to escape both the '"' and the "\". How can I do this in one command? I was hoping the -F would not require me to add extra escaping?

Comment: You might consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ as a matter of habit and fixing what it finds. An unquoted expansion (ie. `$CurrentLog` vs `"$CurrentLog"`) is almost always wrong.

Comment: I'd consider weighing in with my own answer, but the question isn't currently complete enough to allow independent evaluation of whether an answer is fully correct. You might consider trying to add a minimal, complete, verifiable example (per http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- part of what this involves is building an example that includes everything it needs to demonstrate proper function (no off-stage `/usr/local/nagios` files that are used but not shown, for instance; no logs alluded to with processed output but not shown raw; etc), and anything *not* needed for such validation removed.

Comment: ...since, here, you'll only accept an answer if it deals correctly with content coming from `jq`, you might consider providing an example of your JSON-formatted raw input, so folks can answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid escaping double quotes and backslashes you can use single quote around your variable declaration:

```
CurrentLog='2016-08-15 21:02:59,007: 233-670-rundeck-dispatch-script.tmp.sh: Info: Arg: -H server -S SrvCtrl,SNMP -A \"restart\" -CS \"Undefined\" -RS \"Undefined\" -CT \"Undefined\" -RT \"Undefined\" --LogServer logserver:5610'
```

Test the variable content:

```
declare -p CurrentLog
declare -- CurrentLog="2016-08-15 21:02:59,007: 233-670-rundeck-dispatch-script.tmp.sh: Info: Arg: -H server -S SrvCtrl,SNMP -A \\\"restart\\\" -CS \\\"Undefined\\\" -RS \\\"Undefined\\\" -CT \\\"Undefined\\\" -RT \\\"Undefined\\\" --LogServer logserver:5610"
```

Then use it as:

```
grep -qFx "$CurrentLog" file && echo "matched" || echo "nope"

matched
```

Another way is to use here-doc to declare your variable and not be worried about quoting:

```
read -r CurrentLog <<-'EOF'
2016-08-15 21:02:59,007: 233-670-rundeck-dispatch-script.tmp.sh: Info: Arg: -H server -S SrvCtrl,SNMP -A \"restart\" -CS \"Undefined\" -RS \"Undefined\" -CT \"Undefined\" -RT \"Undefined\" --LogServer logserver:5610
EOF
```

Or better avoid creation of a separate variable and use process substitution:

```
read -r CurrentLog < <(jq -r --arg EntryCount "$EntryCount" '.entries[$EntryCoun‌​‌​‌​‌​t | tonumber].log' <<< "$OutputTail")
```

Comment: Hey, I can't put single quotes around my CurrentLog as I get the value like this:
CurrentLog=$(echo $OutputTail | jq ".entries[$EntryCount].log" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' )

Comment: @willemdh: In that case use here-doc as I suggested

Comment: @willemdh, yes, the single-quote suggestion was (entirely correct) for if you're assigning a constant string, which is what you show yourself doing in the question.

Comment: @willemdh, ...frankly, you're using `jq` wrong -- you should be telling it to emit a raw string, not using `sed` to strip quotes in its output.

Comment: Only started using jq since yesterday. I'll look into that. Tx!

Comment: @willemdh, ...but if you're calling this in a loop for each  possible EntryCount value, that's wrong (as in, crazy-inefficient) too; you could easily have `jq` process the whole file at one pass, and read the entries into a shell array from that single invocation.

Comment: I'm indeed using it in a while loop. I'll see about getting it straight into a Bash array.

Comment: If you have trouble doing so, feel free to @-notify me on any separate question you ask on the subject.

Comment: First gotta get this to work.. Still stuck with the escaping. Tried answer 1 method but it seems like so much overhead to create an extra file with the CurrentLog format and my first attempt still seems to fail.

Comment: ...it may not be clear to the OP how to use the heredoc approach when input is actually coming from a pipeline -- need to drop the quoting on the sigil, for instance.

Comment: Yea I'm not sure how to go from 'CurrentLog=$(echo $OutputTail | jq -r ".entries[$EntryCount].log")' to the here doc

Comment: @willemdh, ...btw, I note that you've ignored, several times, my prompt to fix the quoting on the `echo`. Those prompts aren't just for your health; if `OutputTail` contains a `*` with whitespace around it anywhere in the log content, for instance, `echo $OutputTail` will replace it with a list of filenames.

Comment: Yes @CharlesDuffy **`read -r CurrentLog < <(jq -r --arg EntryCount "$EntryCount" '.entries[$EntryCoun‌​‌​‌​t | tonumber].log' <<< "$OutputTail")`** is better (sorry I don't know `jq` well)

Comment: I was able to get it working with the read -r! Tx all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash needs doubling up; the embedded double quotes need an escape (backslash) too.  Hence you end up with `\\\"` appearing in `CurrentLog`.

```
CurrentLog="2016-08-15 21:02:59,007: 233-670-rundeck-dispatch-script.tmp.sh: Info: Arg: -H server -S SrvCtrl,SNMP -A \\\"restart\\\" -CS \\\"Undefined\\\" -RS \\\"Undefined\\\" -CT \\\"Undefined\\\" -RT \\\"Undefined\\\" --LogServer logserver:5610"
```

Also, as [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) reminds me in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962242/grep-string-with-quotes-from-file-not-working/38962357?noredirect=1#comment65279665_38962357), it would be better to use single quotes around the assignment since you don't need any variables expanded or command substitutions made:

```
CurrentLog='2016-08-15 21:02:59,007: 233-670-rundeck-dispatch-script.tmp.sh: Info: Arg: -H server -S SrvCtrl,SNMP -A \"restart\" -CS \"Undefined\" -RS \"Undefined\" -CT \"Undefined\" -RT \"Undefined\" --LogServer logserver:5610'
```

Clearly, if you simplified the string for the question (e.g. the `server` was actually expanded from a variable) then you'd need to revisit this.  Also consider seriously the constructive use of `.*` to match the quoted stuff.  It's unlikely you have several logs with everything the same except that one has `"restart"` and the other has `"Undefined"` at the same point in the string.  Using regexes is a fine art of balancing what's relevant and what's not.

But there comes a point (somewhere a bit before you reach this state), where it is better to but the string to be matched into a file and use the file and fixed string matching with [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html):

```
grep -F -f file-containing-pattern-line file-to-be-searched …
```

You then don't have to fight the shell's quoting and escaping mechanisms (or, at least, only while you're creating `file-containing-pattern-line`).  There's also the `-x` option for 'exact matching of a whole line'.

Don't forget that here documents with quoted words are not interpreted:

```
cat > file-containing-pattern-line << 'EOF'
2016-08-15 21:02:59,007: 233-670-rundeck-dispatch-script.tmp.sh: Info: Arg: -H server -S SrvCtrl,SNMP -A "restart" -CS "Undefined" -RS "Undefined" -CT "Undefined" -RT "Undefined" --LogServer logserver:5610
EOF
```

You should also consider whether you really need to match on all of that.  Would just the data/time be sufficient, or the date/time plus the script name (`233-670-rundeck-dispatch-script.tmp.sh`).  One of those is likely to be sufficient, and matching on just that greatly simplifies the reading of the code.

Comment: If using single-quotes in assigning to `CurrentLog` there would be considerably less fighting going on.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: yes, that too!

Comment: I can't cut the text of as the logs doesn't necessarily start with a date.

Comment: @willemdh: OK — real systems are nasty sometimes, and dealing with them is correspondingly nasty.  You might need to tweak the answer at points; I've not tested it.  But the basic ideas are, I believe, sound.